# vue-i18n - Detect 'unknown' type of token

Tags: vuejs2, vue-i18n

When trying to interpolate values in my translation string using vue-i18n I keep getting this error:

> Detect 'unknown' type of token

My `messages.json` looks as follows:

```
{ test: 
  { "at_location": "At { name }" }
}
```

Usage:

```
<p>
  {{ $t('test.at_location', { name: location.name }) }}
</p>
```

Here `location.name` is defined perfectly fine, so I wonder what's going wrong...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Interpolations in translation messages should not contain spaces.

Change your messages to:

```
{ test: 
  { "at_location": "At {name}" } // No spaces!
}
```